# Two level multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

Let's consider a function whose elaboration time depends on one of its parameter, size, and depending on its value the running time can take from hours to (few) days. In a script I launch multiple instances of this function in parallel to use all the cores and save time.

Let's say that the total elaboration time is limited by the longest running time of function instance with biggest size, and that I can also parallelize some parts of the function: this would probably not be beneficial if all the function instances are running, but it could be beneficial when only one remains (or if I have tons of cores). How would you do this in Python, that is, organize a two-level multiprocessing (one at the script level, the other inside the function)? Or would you just parallelize the function and launch multiple scripts with different configurations?

I provide a MWE, but I understand the answer on the (absolute) fastest execution is probably problem dependent. Here the function consists of nested loops, but you can adapt it as long as it verifies the preceding assumptions, or change the parameters. I am not interested in this particular MWE, but on how to set an inner parallelization.

```
import numpy as np
import time
import timeit
import multiprocessing as mp
import copy


def function_wrapper(matrix):
    """Puts to zero the multiples of 3."""
    side = matrix.shape[0]
    
    # consider to parallelize the following
    # NOTE that I am not interested in parallelizing this particular example 
    # (you can change this part as long as by parallelizing it you better use the cores)
    # with list comprehensions or built-in functions, but on how to setup a second level of multiprocessing
    for x in range(side):
        for y in range(side):
            for z in range(side):
                matrix[x, y, z] = timeit.timeit("numpy.linalg.eig(numpy.random.randint(0, 10, (L, L)))", setup='import numpy; L='+str(matrix[x, y, z]), number=10)

    return matrix

num_cores = mp.cpu_count()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    matrices_number = 20  # depending on the values of matrices_number and max_side the
    max_side = 10         # parallelization setup is more or less important
    matrices = [np.random.randint(1, 101, (side, side, side))
                for side in np.random.randint(2, max_side, matrices_number)]

    # sorts matrices by decreasing shape
    args_generator = sorted([(m,) for m in matrices], key=lambda x: x[0].shape[0], reverse=True)

    iterations = 10  # iterations to reduce caching effects

    start = time.time()
    for k in range(iterations):
        results = [function_wrapper(*args) for args in copy.deepcopy(args_generator)]
    elapsed = time.time() - start
    print(f"loop: elapsed={elapsed} sec.")

    start = time.time()
    for k in range(iterations):
        with mp.Pool(num_cores) as pool:
            results = pool.starmap_async(function_wrapper, copy.deepcopy(args_generator)).get()
    elapsed = time.time() - start
    print(f"mp.Pool: elapsed={elapsed} sec.")
```

Comment: what is the current issue you are facing? is it too slow?

Comment: Indeed the difference between the longest evaluation time and the second last is big, so parallizing the wrapper function would greatly reduce the total evaluation time

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. The code already uses multiprocessing, there is nothing stopping it from using multiprocessing someplace else as well. If you are looking for something more dynamic, where the program is chunked into tasks that may-or-may-not be parallelized over a worker pool, this seems way too broad to answer in general.

Answer (score -1):

You're not taking advantage of the built-in functions in the `numpy` library. You are iterating over the array instead of broadcasting your logic across the whole matrix at once. When you take advantage of the built-in `numpy` functions, you take advantage of the underlying code written in `C`. The wrapper function should be the following.

```
def broadcaster(matrix):
    return np.where(matrix % 3 != 0, matrix, 0)

start = time.time()
    for k in range(iterations):
        results = [broadcaster(*args) for args in copy.deepcopy(args_generator)]
    elapsed = time.time() - start
    print(f"Broadcast: elapsed={elapsed} sec.")
```

When I add that snippet to your code I get the following.

```
loop: elapsed=15.675757884979248 sec.
mp.Pool: elapsed=14.439897060394287 sec.
Broadcast: elapsed=0.6325647830963135 sec.
```

As you can see, in terms of performance, it is not even close.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not answer the question. I am not interested in speeding up this particular MWE, but on how to arrange the two levels of multiprocessing.

Comment: if you showed some code that illustrated your problem a bit better then the answer could be modified. showing a MWE where the solution does not need multiprocessing to achieve a significant speed up, is not a good MWE

Comment: Feel free to change the inner function as long as it verifies the written assumptions, I am interested in the topic not in this particular code